# How do I call matlab member function from C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

Using `mexCallMATLAB(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs, "foo")` command we can call a function(here "foo.m") which was wrote in MATLAB from C++.

But what if "foo" is a method of a class?

```
classdef Foo < handle
    ...
    function out = foo(obj, in)
        ...
    end
end
```

Is there any straightforward or trick to call MATLAB class member function from C++?

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks. I check that and followed to [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-c-1.html) page. But there is no functionality to call member function. Moreover, I used `mex` to create a wrapper and new Q: What is difference(pros/cons) of `mex` and `matlab::engine`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help you since I'm completely unfamiliar with the whole "[MATLAB API for Other Languages](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/programming-interfaces-for-external-languages.html)"...

Comment: Have you tried `mexCallMATLAB(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs, "foo")` setting the first element of prhs an object of class `foo`?

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB you call a class method just like any other function:

```
obj.method
```

is the same as

```
method(obj)
```

You can easily create a similar call from within your MEX-file using `mexCallMATLAB`. If any of the arrays in `prhs` is of type `Foo`, then MATLAB will look for a function first within that class' methods.

So for OP’s example:

```
mxArray rhs = <mxArray of type Foo>;
mcArray los;
mexCallMATLAB(1, &lhs, 1, &rhs, "foo");
```

Comment: How on earth would that compile. `method(obj) `would lead to the mex-compiler going: method not defined.

Comment: @Nozdrum: the MEX-compiler doesn’t know anything about MATLAB functions. You use `mexCallMATLAB` to evaluate the MATLAB expression.

Answer (score -1):

The Foo object would need to be instantiated somewhere so the easiest thing for this example would be to make the foo method static.

You could then create a Matlab wrapper function which calls `Foo.staticfoo(args)` and call the Matlab wrapper function using `mexCallMATLAB`.

Comment: I don't understand why instantiation must be matter but I can tell I cannot change all methods to static. The class already is created and instantiated. Also it has several methods in its floder. So I need something like `mexCallMATLAB(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs, "@Foo/foo")` or `mexCallMATLAB(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs, "@Foo/blabla")`.

Comment: Static methods and why you need them are explained here https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html

If you don't want to use a static method you'll need a specific instance of the class to call the class's method. 

You'll need to write a mechanism of accessing the specific instance of the class in your Matlab  wrapper which you call from c++ using mexCallMATLAB.